# Are we expected to fast today (Matt. 6:16 ff.)?

Tags: matthew, fasting

In the Gospel of Matthew, Christ teaches about fasting:

> **Matthew 6:16-18**: “Whenever you fast, do not put on a gloomy face as the hypocrites do, for they neglect their appearance so that they will be noticed by men when they are fasting. Truly I say to you, they have their reward in full. <sup>17</sup>But you, *when you fast, anoint your head and wash your face <sup>18</sup>so that your fasting will not be noticed by men*, but by your Father who is in secret; and your Father who sees what is done in secret will reward you" (emphasis added).

Is this practice still applicable to us today?

Comment: We don't do contemporary application here.

Comment: Your question has a number of answers on SE-Christianity.

Answer (score 2):

There is almost nothing in the Torah about how fasts were to be observed.  The only specified fast was that associated with Yom Kippur as per Lev 23:27; Num 29:7.  However, fasts were sometimes practiced by the Jews as a way to focus their devotional thoughts either during times of earnest prayer, petition or repentance.

By the time of the NT, the overly religious Pharisees had used such voluntary religious practice as a means to display their confected piety which Jesus condemned on several occasions.

In Matt 6:16-18 Jesus neither commands nor forbids the practice of fasting as a religious observance.  All Jesus commands here is when one elects to use a fast, it should **not** be an occasion for an ostentatious display of piety.  Jesus asks us to make these a private matter between the person and God.

Thus, a Christian fast is a private matter; a voluntary discipline on occasions that suit the individual, and in a manner that suits the intended purpose.

Benson arrives at a similar conclusion.

> Matthew 6:16-18. **When ye fast** — Our Lord does not enjoin either
> fasting, alms-deeds, or prayer, all these being duties which were
> before fully established in the Church of God. **Be not as the
> hypocrites**, &c. — Do not follow the example of the hypocrites, who,
> in order to show that they fast, assume a **sad countenance**; a
> dejected, austere, and mortified look, such as false devotees affect,
> who make piety to consist in outward show, rather than in true
> goodness. **For they disfigure their faces** — Viz., by dust and ashes
> put upon their heads, as was usual in times of mourning and solemn
> humiliation. **Verily, I say unto you, they have their reward** — I
> assure you, persons of this character shall have no other reward but
> the esteem of those whom they deceive by such appearances. **But thou,
> when thou fastest, anoint thy head**, &c. — Come abroad in thine
> ordinary dress. The Jews often anointed their heads. That thou appear
> not, &c. — That, desiring the approbation of God, and not the applause
> of men, thou mayest chiefly be solicitous to appear before God as one
> that fasts; and God, who is ever with thee, and knows thy most secret
> thoughts, shall openly bestow on thee the blessings which belong to a
> true penitent, “whose mortification, contrition, and humility he can
> discern without the help of looks, or dress, or outward expressions of
> any kind. But it must be remembered, that our Lord is speaking here of
> private fasting, to which alone his directions are to be applied; for,
> when public sins or calamities are to be mourned over, the duty of
> fasting ought to be performed in the most public manner.”

Comment: You make some interesting points. +1.

Comment: Yet another reasonable answer that got a downvote without any explanation.  Unless there is something blatantly wrong with an answer, such downvotes are pointless.

Comment: @RayButterworth - I agree - I only downvote if there is something really blatantly or factually wrong which is VERY rare; and then with an explanation!

Comment: @RayButterworth    The downvote was not mine but I would suggest that the answer does not cover occasions when several people fasted (Antioch) or when Jesus suggests people will fast (separately or together). It's not a _full_ answer, I would suggest.